# Kieservices cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

I have installed drools on eclipse and tried to create a test project with simple "hello world" message but it dont run because Kieservices,Kiecontainer and KieSession are not recognized.
How can i solve this ?

The CODE :

```
package com.sample;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

/**
* This is a sample class to launch a rule.
*/
public class DroolsTest {

  public static final void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          // load up the knowledge base
          KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
          KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
          KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

          // go !
          Message message = new Message();
          message.setMessage("Hello World");
          message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
          kSession.insert(message);
          kSession.fireAllRules();
      } catch (Throwable t) {
          t.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public static class Message {

      public static final int HELLO = 0;
      public static final int GOODBYE = 1;

      private String message;

      private int status;

      public String getMessage() {
          return this.message;
      }

      public void setMessage(String message) {
          this.message = message;
      }

      public int getStatus() {
          return this.status;
      }

      public void setStatus(int status) {
          this.status = status;
      }

  }

}
```

The ERROR i am getting when running the code as Java Aplication:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
  KieServices cannot be resolved to a type
  KieServices cannot be resolved
  KieContainer cannot be resolved to a type
  KieSession cannot be resolved to a type

  at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:15)
```

Comment: Because you have not added the corresponding library jar files dependencies for your project. In general people do such dependency management with tools like Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Easiest (and most fragile) way is to right-click on your project > Build path > Add external archives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to select drolls. When you stat a drolls project, click on "Configure Workspace Setting", select drolls content, "add" and dont forget to place a "Tic" in "drolls" before click in "Apply and Close"

Answer (score 1):

Go To Project --> Propertes -->Drools
Click on checkbox - Enable project specific Settings
Select a Drools Runtime which you might have already configured while creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But by selecting Maven for building the project, instead of 'Java and Drools runtime classes', the problem disappeared.